# How to pass route parameters from one Component and display in the other

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm pretty new to the concept of React Router and am currently struggling to understand how I can pass data from one component and the display or use it for performing other functions on the other component. I have used the `useHistory` hook and the `useParams` hook.

This is where I have used the `useHistory` hook

```
const Table = (props) => {
    const data = [];
    const history = useHistory();

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data)

    useEffect(() => {
        setTableData(props.buttonValue)
    }, [props.buttonValue]);

    const tableDataPage = (value) => {
        history.push(`/tableData/${value}`)
    };

    return (
        <div className="tableDataList">
            {!tableData ? "" : <table className="serviceRequestList">

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{ width: "5%" }}>Serial Number<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Name<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Date<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Issue<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                        <th>Status<span><ImFilter size={"12px"} /></span></th>
                    </tr>
                    {tableData.map((value, key) => (
                        <tr key={key} onClick={() => tableDataPage(value.serial_number)}>
                            <td>{value.serial_number}</td>
                            <td>{value.name}</td>
                            <td>{value.date}</td>
                            <td>{value.issue}</td>
                            <td>{value.status}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Table;
```

The component that we get directed to is the one below. However, although the route link has the serial_number showing in it, it doesn't get displayed in either the `div` or the `console.log`. The console log shows an undefined value.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const TableData = () => {
    const { serial_number } = useParams();
    console.log(serial_number);

    return (
        <div>Table Data - {serial_number}</div>
    );
}

export default TableData;
```

[image]

0073 is the serial number in the link and that is what's expected on the screen next to the Table Data text

This here is the App.js file where the routes are declared.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainScreen}></Route>
          <Route path="/addData" component={AddDataScreen}></Route>
          // This is the route in question
          <Route path="/tableData/:id" component={TableData}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Show how you have defined the `/tableData` routes

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli question is now updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your route the parameter is `:id` and that is how you will access it form the params.

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

The route does not care where the param is coming from, it only knows that the dynamic part is named `id`.

Comment: Yes that seems to work. I thought it would have to be the value that is getting pushed from the table component. I did say I'm quite new to React-Router :D :D . Thank You though.

Comment: @coolhack7 you decide the name when you define the route at `<Route path="/tableData/:id"`. I you put there `<Route path="/tableData/:serial_number"` it would work with the original code. Use the naming that makes more sense to you and your app.